# How to create text auto-paragraphs in div?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

How can a new paragraph be created in a div with max width 200px etc.
When my text reaches more than 200px in length, I want a new paragraph to be created in the div.

Is it possible?

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<p style="color:white;">i.e. when max div width (200px) is reached new paragraph is made:</p>

<p class="bubble">Hi Yummi</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p class="bubble">Hi Yummi, how are you <br>do you find your cat?</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

got it solution:

```
max-width:200px;
padding: 15px;
```

PS do not use height:

Comment: This does not create a new paragraph. It just limits the width of the element to 200px, wrapping the typed text to the next line.